# Can I attach an ascii file or use a collapsible panel?

Tags: discussion

I want to publish a somewhat long list of timing processes (~15K lines), related to [Worth using parallel instead of forking processes in a for loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/386629/13011). Specifically, I want to exted the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386974/13011.

Can I attach an ascii file with all timings?
Or, can I use a collapsible panel to click-show/click-hide it's contents?

What is a good way to present such long text material?

Comment: Do you really need 15 *thousand* lines? I can't imagine why all of them would be relevant.

Comment: No, summarize the timings. Use your own words to sum up the results.

Comment: Maybe make ASCII histograms of the data

Comment: @terdon They are timings of processes. ~3600 files x 3 lines reported by `time` plus empty new lines. It's to document the process using GNU Parallel. Ok, I will try to summarise. And maybe some ascii histograms are a good idea!